# Unknown format error in link_to helper in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbo

i am using ruby 3.1.2 and rails 7.0.3.1, i have changed the edit request get to post in the routes file
app/config/routes

```
 resources :users do
    member do
      post :edit
    end
  end
```

app/views/users/index.html.erb

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <div id="users">
        <%= render user %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

app/views/users/_user.html.erb
add link_to in _user.html.erb partial

```
<%= link_to "Edit this user", edit_user_path(user), method: :post %>
```

app/controller/users_controller.rb

```
def edit
    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream do
        render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update("new_user", partial: "users/form", locals: { user: User.find(params[:id]) } ) 
      end
    end
  end
```

getting unknown format error when trying to edit user.

thanks!

Comment: `method: :post` is the option for the old Rails UJS driver. For Turbo you use `data: { turbo_method: "post" }`. However Spickermann is completely right in that you should use GET and not POST here. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#method

Answer (score 0):

Edit routes are automatically generated when you define `resources :users` in your `config/routes.rb`. And edit routes are `GET`.

Just remove the `member` definition from your routes file and change the `link_to` in the partial to:

```
<%= link_to "Edit this user", edit_user_path(user) %>
```

Btw. you can call `rails routes` on your command line to see all routes that are available in your app, how they are named, HTTP method and what controller and method they route to.

Comment: still getting the same error unknown format for edit action

Comment: Check your Rails logs. If the request is being treated as HTML by Rails then you most likely have a JavaScript error thats preventing Turbo from working properly. The next step is to use the web inspector in your browser to ensure that there are no script errors and that the correct assets are loaded. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbo

Comment: i have used button_to instead of link_to helper it's working perfectly as we wanted.